# concat two arrays together in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, arrays, group-by, google-bigquery

I'm trying to take two arrays, and concatenate the two together. I have had good success in previous iterations of my data if the data was coming from a record, but these two distinct arrays are giving me problems.

I have JSON in this structure:
`{"actor": "Tim Curry", "title" : ["Rocky Horror Picture Show", "Mighty Max", "Spamalot"], "result":["Nominated for Award","Nominated for Award", "Won Whatsonstage.com Award"]}`

and thus a BQ table that looks like this

[image]

I am trying to concatenate the two array together, matching up the index position from one array to the index of the other, ultimately ending up with this

[image]

I believe that I will need a statement that look something like this `SELECT actor, ARRAY_TO_STRING(movie_and_award, ',    ') movie_and_award FROM t`  but I just cannot figure out how is that I'm going to generatre the `movie_and_award` array that gets passed to `ARRAY_TO_STRING`.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT actor, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
    SELECT x || ' : ' || y 
    FROM UNNEST(t.title) x WITH OFFSET
    JOIN UNNEST(t.result) y WITH OFFSET
    USING(OFFSET)
  ), ', ') movie_and_award
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row actor       movie_and_award  
1   Tim Curry   Rocky Horror Picture Show : Nominated for Award, Mighty Max : Nominated for Award, Spamalot : Won Whatsonstage.com Award
```